# How to change samba user SID?

Tags: samba, active-directory

I'm trying to change the SID of various user in Samba 4.1.14 using pdbedit

```
pdbedit --user <username> SID=<SID>
```

I run the command but no message is displayed nor the SID is changed.

How can I modify users' SID in Samba 4.1.14?

Comment: I have the same problem, somehow I have two same SID's so I want to change them.

Comment: Two users with the same SID? Are you using only one server? My problem, which I left aside for undetermined time, is that I want to change my domain name but avoid creating "new users" on each machine when the users login using the new domain. For example perry.platypus has a SID S-1-5-21-2447931902-1787058256-3961074038-5004 on the old domain but on the new domain he has S-1-5-21-2447931902-1787058256-4461074038-2222, when he logs in in the new domain Windows will create a new user folder perry.platypus.NEWDOMAIN. That's a huge problema for me.

Comment: I recommend you start using compiled version of samba to keep it updated.

Comment: I've tested with 4.1.14, 4.1.21, 4.2.1 e 4.3.1 and is not working. They should have removed it since it doesn't work in any version.

Comment: it seams that in your case you'll have to choose one user to exclude from the domain and recreate the user. There was, I think it was removed from Sysinternals, a tool called NewSID or something like that. I think you can still find it. NewSID can change the local Windows user SID avoding having to copy all the user's data to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Years later...
There is no way to do that!
For the mentioned versions at the time. I tried!

Answer (score 2):

Samba 4 domain controllers [ignore `pdbedit`'s attempts to set SIDs](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2013-April/172486.html). To change a user's SID, you'll have to use the `ldb-tools` package to [edit the SAM LDB](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LDB#ldbedit) in the Samba state directory directly. New Samba versions have a `private/sam.ldb.d` subdirectory containing one LDB file per naming context, e.g. `DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM.ldb`; some versions might just have the `private/sam.ldb` file.

**Caution:** It is a good idea to back up the Samba domain before tinkering with its state.

Once you've identified the file of interest, stop the Samba service. Invoke `ldbedit` to edit one record in that LDB specified by the username whose SID needs to be adjusted:

```
sudo ldbedit -e nano -H /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb.d/DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM.ldb '(samaccountname=someone)'
#               ~~~~                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                  ~~~~~~~
#          editor of choice                             LDB of interest                        username
```

**Caution:** You are responsible for making sure the SID you choose is not also used by an existing or future account.

Adjust the SID on the `objectSid` line, save the file, and exit the text editor. `ldbedit` will apply the change and you can restart the Samba service.

Comment: It would be nice for some more people to test it. Nowadays, with the current versions, I don't know if it would really work, and I don't work on the place anymore nor have some server to test it.

Comment: Yes, it works. For me, /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb didn't work, I had to use /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb.d/DC*

Answer (score 0):

`pdbedit --user youruser -U NEWSID`

Answer (score 0):

@msmafra I tested it with Samba 4.11.2 on CentOS 8 and it works.

Also it can be run on a single line without editors, as follows. -e parameter can be use with other commands like sed, cat and etc.

```
ldbedit -e 'sed -i "s/OLD_SID/NEW_SID/g"' -H /var/lib/samba/private/sam.ldb.d/DC\=EXAMPLE\,DC\=LAB.ldb "(objectSid=OLD_SID)"
```

Comment: Good idea for batch changes.